# Pentaho Server 9.4 installation issues

Tags: pentaho

I've just completed all the steps to install Pentaho Server 9.4 CE, and unfortunately it is not working.

Tomcat is starting, the PUC page appears, but any login fails.

Looking at the catalina.log, I can see a first error:

```
14:38:39,139 ERROR [SchemaUpdate] could not get database metadata
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver from ClassLoader:ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: pentaho
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@7aec35a
;ClassLoader:ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: pentaho
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@7aec35a
```

Later down the log, there's another error:
14:38:39,397 ERROR [SchemaUpdate] could not complete schema update
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver from ClassLoader:ParallelWebappClassLoader
context: pentaho
delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:

which, I guess, is caused by Tomcat trying to access the sample data provided by Pentaho, which probably doesn't exist.

I found other errors, but removing these first will help cleaning up the situation.

Any help appreciated.

I followed all the steps mentioned in the Pentaho Setup instructions for Archive mode.
I would have expected to be able to start working with the server immediately, but that was not the case.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the jdbc driver for the database that you are currently using.